# How to capture wikipedia API extracts

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have achieved some success using the wikipedia api, but I am needing some help capturing the returned data, and displaying it to a page.  Link to my codepen is https://codepen.io/rynsp8/pen/jYyYog, but code snippet is below as well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var searchTERM = $('#searchTERM');
  var wiki_URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php';

  $('#randBTN').click(function(){
  window.open('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random');
  });

  $('#searchBTN').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: wiki_URL,
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {
        action: 'query',
        format: 'json',
        prop: 'extracts|links',
        exintro: '1',
        pllimit: '10',
        titles: searchTERM.val()
      },
      //headers: {'Api-User-Agent' : 'Example/1.0'},
      success: function(results){
        $('#searchRESULTS').text(results.query.pages);
        console.log(results);
      }
    })
  })
  console.log(searchTERM.val());
})
```

I am seeing a response in the javascript console, which, at this stage of the game, is fairly exciting for me, that I'm doing something right.

I can see that data is being sent back, and there is an extract in my console for Star Wars, my test search, and my title, Star Wars...

I'm on the right track, I just need to know how to display the information in my page.  The only thing that displays is, [object Object].  Below is my HTML

```
<div>
  <div id="mainCTN">
    <div id="topCTN">
      <h1>Wiki Viewer</h1>
      <button id="randBTN">Random Article</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="searchTERM" placeholder="search"></input>
    <button id="searchBTN">SEARCH</button>
    </div>
  <div id="searchRESULTS"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the thing you're trying to print on page is a JavaScript object, which is, when stringified, turns into `[object Object]`. This is JavaScript's behaviour.

But to show the contents on the page, you need go through the element, and extract the particular information that you want to show on the page.

Refer to the following snippet, which prints the `extract` of each article fetched from the API. Just try to search for something, for example **test**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var searchTERM = $('#searchTERM');
  var wiki_URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php';

  $('#randBTN').click(function() {
    window.open('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random');
  });

  $('#searchBTN').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: wiki_URL,
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {
        action: 'query',
        format: 'json',
        prop: 'extracts|links',
        exintro: '1',
        pllimit: '10',
        titles: searchTERM.val()
      },
      //headers: {'Api-User-Agent' : 'Example/1.0'},
      success: function(results) {
        $('#searchRESULTS').html('');
        Object.keys(results.query.pages).forEach(key => {
          $('#searchRESULTS').html($('#searchRESULTS').html() + results.query.pages[key].extract);
        });
      }
    })
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div id="mainCTN">
    <div id="topCTN">
      <h1>Wiki Viewer</h1>
      <button id="randBTN">Random Article</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="searchTERM" placeholder="search"></input>
      <button id="searchBTN">SEARCH</button>
    </div>
    <div id="searchRESULTS">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  I'll have to spend some time examining what you added to understand what you did.  But thanks for the help.